Display Images from cloudinary in nextjs
I have added the images to cloudinary but I don't know how to display them in my nextjs website. I'm not really sure how to use the src field.
I was able to use the id of each image but I'm not sure how to display all the images using their IDs in the sec field

Hi, you can use the CldImage component as described in this document, and you may also check out this NextJS sample project.
